# Auto insert default record when deploying Spring MVC App with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jpa-2.0

I am looking for a way to auto insert a default admin account, using JPA, when my spring mvc application is deployed.

My database is generated based on the Entities.

I want to kick off something that will insert a default admin user, assign roles, every time the application is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which implementation of JPA you use. 
If you use `Hibernate` you can add `import.sql` file (that contains records to load) to the class path. More info [here](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Data_Services/5/html/Metadata_Repository_Reference_Guide/jdbc-storage-connector.html).

As a workaround you can also use [dbunit](http://www.dbunit.org/) tool.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend having a migration utility that will keep your database in synch with your codebase - these are typically DDL's, but again the queries to insert default admin user, assign roles etc can also be part of this migration utility. There are very good one's available - [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) is one that I have used, [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) is another one.

There is a very good comparison of the different migration utilities on the Flyway homepage also that you can look at.

Answer (score 0):

i use CommandLineRunner interface.

```
@Component    
public class CommandLineAppStartupRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(String...args) throws Exception {
        User admin = new user(firstName);
        userRepository.save(admin);
    }
}
```

before the app starts this class will be executed.

you can find other ways here : [Guide To Running Logic on Startup in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring)